# Add generated column to an existing table Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to add a generated column to an existing table with this script.

```
alter table Asset_Store add column

md5_hash VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS 

(CAST(UPPER(    
        case
             when OR_ID is not null then MD5(cast(OR_ID as varchar(100)))
             when Asset_ID is not null then MD5(Asset_ID)
             else null
        end 
) as VARCHAR(100)))

STORED

;
```

but I am getting an error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
 Position: 88
 ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
 Position: 88
 ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
 Position: 88
```

What is the issue? I don't get it.

In the schema of my Asset_Store table the column
OR_ID is `int` and Asset_ID is `varchar(100)`.

I guess it expects a slightly different syntax... but what is the right syntax?

Comment: Version of PostgreSQL? It was introduced in 12.

Comment: What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I realized later that I was on PG 11.

Comment: Should I go ahead and delete this question?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your syntax is correct.  Your version of PostgreSQL apparently is not.

In version 12:

```
create table asset_store(or_id text, asset_id text);

alter table Asset_Store add column
md5_hash VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
(CAST(UPPER(    
        case
             when OR_ID is not null then MD5(cast(OR_ID as varchar(100)))
             when Asset_ID is not null then MD5(Asset_ID)
             else null
        end 
) as VARCHAR(100)))
STORED
;
```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE
> Time: 17.678 ms
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I realized later that I was on PG 11.

Comment: For future copy-pasters, neither of the `CAST (... as VARCHAR(100))` expressions were necessary for me in my different SQL.

Answer (score 5):

More general, simplified command

```sql
ALTER TABLE "items"
ADD COLUMN "revenue" numeric 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("price" * (1-"discount")) STORED;
```