# Inserting st_length function doesn't match row numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am new to sql/postgres and am trying to run st_length on a database geometry and insert the length as a cost column but the result from running the following commands inserts the data seemingly randomly and not associated with the id column value like needed.

Command:

```
alter table planet_osm_roads add cost float;
insert into planet_osm_roads (cost)
select st_length(st_transform(way, 4326)::geography) from planet_osm_roads;
```

example result:

| source | target | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30,749 | 30,750 |  |
| 30,751 | 30,752 |  |
| 7,552 | 30,385 |  |
|  |  | 7.6144929361 |
|  |  | 41.7331770846 |
|  |  | 85.3575622508 |
|  |  | 50.0921684238 |
| 3 | 4 |  |
|  |  | 111.5246694513 |
|  |  | 43.8658606368 |

I've ignored the other columns as they aren't needed. The columns with 'source' and 'target' values are associated with a specific 'osm_id' value and the cost column is null for those but the commands don't associated the cost value with the linestring row value.

I would expect the cost value to be inserted in the same row as to which the linestring data comes from. That is not what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert adds new rows. You want to Update the table and Set cost where some row matches.

```
ALTER TABLE planet_osm_roads ADD cost FLOAT;

UPDATE planet_osm_roads
   SET cost = 7.6144929361
 WHERE source = 30,749
    or target = something 
    or both
```

It's possible to do this from a select but how depends on your schema and data. Depending on your version of PostGres, you may even be able to do it with a generated column - [Add generated column to an existing table Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727318/add-generated-column-to-an-existing-table-postgres)

Comment: So the following was what I was looking for and you helped me get there. I wanted to add the distances for the tables of road ways/linestrings from osm data. "update planet_osm_roads set cost = st_length(st_transform(way, 4326)::geography);"